# Параметр высоты в резиновой верстке

Tags: jquery, вёрстка, css, javascript

Есть картинка, которая при изменении размеров окна ресайзится до 100% ширины от окна.

```
<img src="" style="width: 100%">
```

Как узнать при этом высоту растянутого блока в котором содержится картинка?

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    alert($('img').height());
});
```

Не подходит. Ставлю брекпойнт, проверяю высоту - 0. При чем работает странно - не всегда 0, но в 80% случаев. В остальных 20% высота определяется верно.

Comment: а в атрибуте src должно быть пусто?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/b9grf/

Comment: > а в атрибуте src должно быть пусто?

Ну это чисто для примера

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8613562/javascript-jquery-how-to-detect-img-is-fully-downloaded-or-not

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Это как раз тот случай, когда надо проверять complete.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var $img = $('img').first();
    if ($img.prop('complete')) show_size();
    else $img.on('load', show_size);

    function show_size() {
        alert($img.height());
    }
});
```

Comment: Потрясает! Пожалуйста, ткните носом, где можно ознакомиться со списком всех доступных properties?

Comment: ну вы же знаете... mdn,  стандарт html, описание ecmascript (первые два для DOM, последний - общий)

на ходу - консоли браузера

    var a=new Image;
    a.[всплывающая подсказка со всеми свойствами и методами]

Comment: > ну вы же знаете...

В front-end мой путь только-только начинается, учитывая, что пол года этим занимаюсь =) Поэтому узнать еще, чувствую, предстоит много.